# Is OAuth2 Password grant type and client_credential grant types the same?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

As I understand before messing with Laravel Passport, **password** grant type is resource owner type and **client_credential** is for first party app, so basically routes protected with **client_credential** can access with token issues by itself,

My problem is token issued from password grant type can access routes protected by client_credential, and routes protected by `api:auth` can't be access by **client_credential** token

Answer (score 2):

These are two different flow types.

First you need to understand the different between client and resource owner. This is explained clearly on [roles](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) section of the protocol.

> **resource server**
>
> The server hosting the protected resources, capable of accepting and
> responding to protected resource requests using access tokens.
>
> **client**
>
> An application making protected resource requests on behalf of the
> resource owner and with its authorization.

Now, the flows you have mentioned use credentials from resource owner and client. The clients in client credential flow are confidential clients. That means they have a client secret with them.

In resource owner password grant, you obtain tokens from token endpoint by presenting resource owner credentials. For client credential grant type, you obtain tokens from token endpoint by presenting client credentials. So as you can see they are two different flows.

Depending on the implementation, tokens issued for these flows could have different scopes. That mean, those tokens may have a different validity or could have limitations. Such restrictions are independent of OAuth 2.0 protocol.

Comment: oh I got it, your point is token issued by Password grant type is belong to both owner and client, that's why the token can access endpoints protected by `client` and `api:auth`.